# .exe file Failed due to exception in main class

Tags: java, ant, javafx, build, exe

I made an app using javafx and packaged it as exe file. It works fine being started from eclipse but being installed it says

> Failed due to exception in main class

no matter what pc it was started at. I've found a few same questions but everyone found solution by themselves but don't tell how. One question has an answer:

> the issue were VM parameters I added in the build.xml in the
>   fx:platform / fx:jvmarg section. These params were put into the
>   package.cfg file which is called from the .exe file to initialize the
>   VM.

In my build.xml there is only one string related to the named `fx:platform` But in my case there is only `<fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>` and nothing else. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exception? Try running the executable from the console and try running the executable jar from the console with `java -jar <executable-jar>`. And post the results as part of your question.

Comment: @hotzst I didn't know about such a possibility to launch it from the console. I've found problem in the exception description and this resolved my problem. The problem was that the fxml is called main.fxml and I used in main method Main.fxml. Don't know why it worked being runned from the eclipse