# Failed due to exception from main class in others computers

Tags: java, javafx, deployment

i developed a JavaFX application and i deployed as .exe , and when i install at my computer everything works fine. but after i install .exe to another computer and i try to open app , it shows me an error:

**Failed due to Exception from main class.**

Can someone please help me with this error?

build.fxml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- You may freely edit this file. See commented blocks below for --><!-- some examples of how to customize the build. --><!-- (If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.) --><!-- By default, only the Clean and Build commands use this build script. --><project name="Main" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project Main.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
    <!--

    There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
    used for execution of your tasks. These targets are usually executed 
    before and after some main targets. Those of them relevant for JavaFX project are: 

      -pre-init:                 called before initialization of project properties
      -post-init:                called after initialization of project properties
      -pre-compile:              called before javac compilation
      -post-compile:             called after javac compilation
      -pre-compile-test:         called before javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -post-compile-test:        called after javac compilation of JUnit tests
      -pre-jfx-jar:              called before FX SDK specific <fx:jar> task
      -post-jfx-jar:             called after FX SDK specific <fx:jar> task
      -pre-jfx-deploy:           called before FX SDK specific <fx:deploy> task
      -post-jfx-deploy:          called after FX SDK specific <fx:deploy> task
      -pre-jfx-native:           called just after -pre-jfx-deploy if <fx:deploy> runs in native packaging mode
      -post-jfx-native:          called just after -post-jfx-deploy if <fx:deploy> runs in native packaging mode
      -post-clean:               called after cleaning build products

    (Targets beginning with '-' are not intended to be called on their own.)

    Example of inserting a HTML postprocessor after javaFX SDK deployment:

        <target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
            <basename property="jfx.deployment.base" file="${jfx.deployment.jar}" suffix=".jar"/>
            <property name="jfx.deployment.html" location="${jfx.deployment.dir}${file.separator}${jfx.deployment.base}.html"/>
            <custompostprocess>
                <fileset dir="${jfx.deployment.html}"/>
            </custompostprocess>
        </target>

    Example of calling an Ant task from JavaFX SDK. Note that access to JavaFX SDK Ant tasks must be
    initialized; to ensure this is done add the dependence on -check-jfx-sdk-version target:

        <target name="-post-jfx-jar" depends="-check-jfx-sdk-version">
            <echo message="Calling jar task from JavaFX SDK"/>
            <fx:jar ...>
                ...
            </fx:jar>
        </target>

    For more details about JavaFX SDK Ant tasks go to
    http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm

    For list of available properties check the files
    nbproject/build-impl.xml and nbproject/jfx-impl.xml.

    -->

</project>
```

I also tried to change build.fxml to this but still the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- You may freely edit this file. See commented blocks below for --><!-- some examples of how to customize the build. --><!-- (If you delete it and reopen the project it will be recreated.) --><!-- By default, only the Clean and Build commands use this build script. --><project name="AutoMekanikAdmin" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<description>Builds, tests, and runs the project AutoMekanikAdmin.</description>
<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
<!--

There exist several targets which are by default empty and which can be 
used for execution of your tasks. These targets are usually executed 
before and after some main targets. Those of them relevant for JavaFX project are: 

  -pre-init:                 called before initialization of project properties
  -post-init:                called after initialization of project properties
  -pre-compile:              called before javac compilation
  -post-compile:             called after javac compilation
  -pre-compile-test:         called before javac compilation of JUnit tests
  -post-compile-test:        called after javac compilation of JUnit tests
  -pre-jfx-jar:              called before FX SDK specific <fx:jar> task
  -post-jfx-jar:             called after FX SDK specific <fx:jar> task
  -pre-jfx-deploy:           called before FX SDK specific <fx:deploy> task
  -post-jfx-deploy:          called after FX SDK specific <fx:deploy> task
  -pre-jfx-native:           called just after -pre-jfx-deploy if <fx:deploy> runs in native packaging mode
  -post-jfx-native:          called just after -post-jfx-deploy if <fx:deploy> runs in native packaging mode
  -post-clean:               called after cleaning build products

(Targets beginning with '-' are not intended to be called on their own.)

Example of inserting a HTML postprocessor after javaFX SDK deployment:

    <target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
        <basename property="jfx.deployment.base" file="${jfx.deployment.jar}" suffix=".jar"/>
        <property name="jfx.deployment.html" location="${jfx.deployment.dir}${file.separator}${jfx.deployment.base}.html"/>
        <custompostprocess>
            <fileset dir="${jfx.deployment.html}"/>
        </custompostprocess>
    </target>

Example of calling an Ant task from JavaFX SDK. Note that access to JavaFX SDK Ant tasks must be
initialized; to ensure this is done add the dependence on -check-jfx-sdk-version target:

    <target name="-post-jfx-jar" depends="-check-jfx-sdk-version">
        <echo message="Calling jar task from JavaFX SDK"/>
        <fx:jar ...>
            ...
        </fx:jar>
    </target>

For more details about JavaFX SDK Ant tasks go to
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm

For list of available properties check the files
nbproject/build-impl.xml and nbproject/jfx-impl.xml.

-->
<target name="post-jfx-deploy">
    <fx:deploy verbose="true" nativeBundles="exe" outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
        <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}" />
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" include="*.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" include=";ib/*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}" />
        <fx:info>
            <fx:icon href="${basedir}/icon.ico"></fx:icon>
        </fx:info>
        <fx:preferences shortcut="true" />
    </fx:deploy>
</target>
```

Comment: Kyle Warford links to a question that mentions an “exception description.”  Do you have any way to see the exception’s description?

Answer (score 1):

did you use any VM parameters while building? This SE post comes up when  searching the error:[JavaFX failed due to exception in main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212291/javafx-exe-file-failed-due-to-exception-in-main-class).

try running the executable and the jar from the console, for debugging:

> What is the exception? Try running the executable from the console and try running the executable jar from the console with java -jar . And post the results as part of your question.

[running from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087423/exe-file-failed-due-to-exception-in-main-class)

Comment: Yes i used VM parameters in ProjectFile>Properties>Run>VM Options: -Xms512m , also check build.fxml i added

Answer (score 0):

This is java problem. If you don't add java to your exe bundle, then application use system java. You can add java to your exe bundle. Then, application use that java. If you use to create exe with ant then add this parameter in build.xml;

```
    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
```

Comment: Where should i add this one , because i used ProjectFile>Package as> EXE Installer to made that .exe file

Comment: I think you are using ant for creating exe. You can add this

Comment: Previous one is for gradle. This one is for ant.

Comment: No I'm using InnoSetup 5

Comment: Ok. Ant is using innoSetup for creating exe. Is there build.xml file in project ?

Comment: Check my answer .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that these other computers didnt had JavaJDK installed , but they had only JavaJRE. So i executed jar file from CMD java -jar  , and while it was executed it created database tables , that it should to .